# About javascript function valueOf\toString and 'curry' function behaved differently in Chrome,Firefox and node enviroment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I wrote a function:

```
function add(){
    let arr = [];
    arr = arr.concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments))
    let fun = function(){
        arr = arr.concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments))
        return fun
    }
    fun.toString = function(){
        console.log(222)
        return arr.reduce(function(total, num){
            return total+num
        }, 0)
    }
    return fun
}
console.log(add(1,2)(2,3)(3))
```

This is in Chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSxb3.png)

Two questions:

1. In first line, why is `'f 11'` ,not `'11'`?
2. Why output `'f 11'` firstly, not `'222'`, I think the type conversion should execute firstly, and then output computed result on console.

Another strange thing, it is the result in Firefox with same codes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMUXS.png)

And the result in node environment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVfx3.png)

I do not understand why, it seems in FF and node, has not executed the computed operation.

Please help me...Thanks so much!

Comment: The *f* means *function* which is correct

Comment: What is the point of any of this? Why do you have to call `toString` to get the value out? That's completely counter-intuitive. Trying to have an `add` function that is both variadic and curried at the same time is...weird.

Comment: @JonasW. correct function?

Comment: @JaredSmith I agree with you.That's a question that others asked me.If I do that ,I guess should be like this:add(1)(2).getValue()...But the question do not allow 'getValue', so I have to call toString or valueOf to get the value out.

Comment: @JonasW. I see, just like this:var app = function(){}; app.toString = function(){  return 11 }; function app1(){  return app }; console.log(app1()).Chrome return 'f11',FF and node return function 'app'.Only on Chrone app.toString was called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you can beautify the whole code a bit:

```
function add(..arr){
  function fun(...args){
   arr.push(...args);
   return fun
  }

  fun.toString = function(){
    return arr.reduce((total, num) => total + num)
  };
  return fun;
}
```

And as you noticed correctly, logging a function is completely up to the environment. Firefox and Node return the code of the function, while Chrome does sth like:

```
out( "f" + add.toString())
```

so our toString function gets called and something is logged. To have a consistent behaviour between the different environments we could call toString explicitly:

```
console.log(add(1)(2)(3).toString());
```

This can be inferred:

```
console.log("" + add(1)(2));
```

Comment: Yeah,u r right.That could be a good solution. But I want to know why a function is outputed, not a value, and in FF or node ,'console.log(222)' seems not be executed...

Comment: @daXiong `Firefox and Node return the code of the function, while Chrome does sth like:`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is `add` that is both variadic and curried (which I still think is weird), just do this:

```
const add = (...args) => {
  let accum = args;
  let f = (...fargs) => {
    if (!fargs.length) {
      return accum.reduce((a, b) => { return a + b; }, 0);
    } else {
      accum = accum.concat(fargs);
      return f;
    }
  };
  return f;
};

add(1,2,3)(); // 6
add(1)(2,3)(); // 6
add()(); // 0
```

Now you just call the returned function with no arguments to get the value out. You could toy with it to make it more performant (e.g. by using `.push` in a loop instead of `.concat`) but this should work.

Comment: ...or `accum.push(...fargs)`

Comment: Thank u.I got it.That's a nice idea!